# Use inheritance only for polymorphism in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I´m designing a project in C++ and got to the point where I´m in doubt whereas I should use inheritance just to have polymorphism.

Specifically, I have a class `JazzQuartet` which has 4 objects: `Saxophonist`, `Pianist`, `Bassist` and `Drummer`, each with a `play()` and `listen()` methods, with different implementations.

I´d like to make them all inherit from a class `Musician` so I can have an array of `Musician` objects and call each one´s `play()` and `listen()` methods, and also so I can make any `Musician` `listen()` to any other. But as their implementation is completely different from each other, I´d be using this heritage just to get polymorphism, and I´m not sure if that´s a good design choice.

Any advice on this matter?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: yes, polymorphism would be solved your problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"... so I can have an array of Musician objects and call each one´s play() and listen() methods, and also so I can make any Musician listen() to any other."*

`Musician` should be an abstract class, i.e. an interface:

```
 class Musician {
 public:
     virtual void play() = 0;
     virtual void listen(Musician& other) = 0;
     virtual bool isPlaying() = 0;
     virtual ~Musician() {}
 };
```

And yes it's considered good design to promote interfaces.

This way you enforce that derived classes must implement these functions, and allow clients to access `Musician` instances, without need to know the concrete derived type.

As you've been asking to store the whole ensemble into an array:

With the above design you can use an array of `std::unique_ptr<Musician>` to aggregate a particular ensemble of musicians.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Musician>> jazzQuartet(4);
std::unique_ptr<Saxophonist> sax = new Saxophonist();
std::unique_ptr<Pianist> piano = new Pianist();
std::unique_ptr<Bassist> bass = new Bassist();
std::unique_ptr<Drummer> drums = new Drummer();

jazzQuartet[0] = sax;
jazzQuartet[1] = piano;
jazzQuartet[2] = bass;
jazzQuartet[3] = drums;

// And wire them up as necessary
//------------------------------------

// Usually everyone in the combo needs to listen to the drums
sax->listen(*drums);
piano->listen(*drums);
bass->listen(*drums);

...

// Let them all play
for(auto& m : jazzQuartet) { // Note the & to avoid copies made for the items
    m->play();
}
```

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but you should include a virtual destructor in there too.

Comment: Guess I should also make JazzQuartet inherit from a pure virtual "Band" class then... I was´t familiar with this interface concept for C++, thought it only existed in Java. Thank you!

Comment: @Lajotas Yes, `Band` could provide that array as mentioned, and concrete implementations (e.g. `JazzQuartet`) should provide the array (`std::vector`) initialization code I have shown.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I have another question about this design, gonna make a new post, hope you can help there as well :)

Comment: @Lajotas Well, you might notify me here about another question, if I don't catch it from the [tag:c++] filtered newest questions queue. Though you should think over your question format when applying the [tag:c++] tag. Your questions should be decorated with a more concrete (even pseudo-) code sample, than just writing prose. I was tempted as a 1st impulse to close your question as being _too broad_ and as you can see from the count of various answers I wouldn't have been too wrong doing so.

Comment: Oh, I´m really sorry about that... I haven´t really began writing the code, or in fact I have but I noticed that my design wasn´t clear and decided to think it through before continuing. I´m going to be more careful with my questions in the future, I´m new to both programming and to this forum. Anyway the answers were very helpful, hope it helps other people too :) Thank you!

Comment: @Lajotas UML scribbling could be helpful in this phase.

Comment: I´m trying to draw the UML on paper, but I´m not very familiar with the codes... Would you recommend any software or tutorial regarding this? I´ve looked it up but ended more confused than I was before... Also, can I post UML as part of the question in this forum? Thank you again in advance.

Comment: @Lajotas Well, I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect for UML drawings (which is a commercial software), but pencil and paper (and a bin for the screwed sheets) isn't the worst approach to do it. Doing UML on the desktop there are also some Eclipse plugins available, but I didn't like them as much as EA. And of course you could post a pic of your UML drawings (even scanned from paper), to clarify your question.

Answer (score 7):

I see no reason to worry that your `Musician` implementations will not have any common code. In fact this is exactly what is called [Pure Abstract Class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes/Pure_Abstract_Classes). In general, this is good idea to separate interface concepts.

It gives you more advantages then the ones you have mentioned, most important that you will most probably find that your other code does not need to know what particular type of `Musician` it is working with, and thus your main code will be simpler.

And that's also not "just" polymorphism, it also promotes encapsulation a lot as the users will be forced to use `Musician` interface.

Also, I think that in future you might find that you actually *need* some common code between different musicians (say, the director/conductor object reference?).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, wish I could vote two right answers!

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfectly reasonable usage of polymorphism.  `Saxophonist`, `Pianist`, `Bassist`, and `Drummer` all exhibit an "Is-a" relationship with `Musician`.

Your `Musician` class would be pure virtual (also called an Interface).

Answer (score 2):

Just to be advocato diavolo,

you can also use composition - e.g. you have single class Musician and 2 delegate, non virtual methods - listen and play. Then you should have 4 more claeses, each for each type of musicians. Then in Musician constructor you will provide class from those four clases.

But big but - you once again will need base class. And advantages of composition / delegating / strategy "pattern" are doubious, at least in this case.

This only means your current aproach is sound. Go with inheritance :)

Comment: Got your point, think I´ll stick to the golden "is a" vs. "has a" rule, and use composition for other aspects of the design. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Don't see so much desire to use a _double dispatch_ for this particular kind of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Application growth is the main factor here. Unless this is for academic practice only (in which case it will have educational value), it will not if the application is not growing.  One of the things we have to be careful is to never over-engineer solutions.  Our solutions should always be the simplest that addresses the business needs.  Why? Simply because, we cannot predict the future and, we need to ensure our efforts go towards solutions which will provide value to our clients and because of that to ourselves.  Otherwise, if you have come to a point where your application is growing and the current design is getting in the way, which may be where you are now, we need enhance the design. To answer your question polymorphism could enhance your design in the following areas:

First, Since all musicians will implement the **Musician** interface, they will all be able to play and listen polymorphically , i.e. you could loop through your array.  This is the main benefit of polymorphism.

Second, It will make code reuse and enhancing the application easier.  For example, it will make it easy to add musicians in the future.  All it takes is to take a look at the interface to know what methods a musician needs to implement. In terms of code reuse, in a larger application, you could reuse most of your code on an orchestra application for instance.

Third, refactoring becomes easier in future iterations.  For example, say you need to re-implement the play() method on the Pianist nothing else will need to be changed on JazzQuartet whereas if you leave it as it is you may need to.  How?  Implementing to an interface is also called **design by contract** because, it forces the subclass to implement the methods as specified on the interface.  You do not have that restriction with your existing design so nothing stops you or another committer from changing the name of the play method to say PianistPlay which will make a change to JazzQuartet necessary.

Fourth, It improves maintainability.  It will certainly be more clear to the person maintaining the code that these four objects are related and implement the same interface than if they remain four distinct objects.  That is looking at the interface may be enough in most cases to determine how to use or enhance the objects.  On the other hand simply using the objects will require to look at each implementation which depending how large the application is growing may be quite tedious.  Things may get very complicated when attempting to enhance the unique objects.  If you are using an interface and you want to add a new method, you will have to go to each class and implement it, but imagine trying to do the same without the interface, it could be quite similar if using good naming conventions and quite tedious if not, i.e. if the all play methods include the name of the class for example bassistPlay().

Comment: Please at least improve your answers formatting (paragraphs), and give some concise code samples.

Comment: Being cognizant, this may very well be a homework assignment, I think it a wrong to provide a complete solution not to mention that as worded this is a **design** question.  Nevertheless, I do think you are right about your first assertion, I have not given my answer a fair chance so I have edited it so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Also, you could be potentially robbing a new programmer the opportunity to learn from their own experiences and instead creating dependency to others.  Worse, you are not answering the question, namely, how polymorphism will improve the design?  Without the code your answer sums up to a simple **yes**.  Because you got distracted with code you fail to do that.  I hope that now that I have expressed my views and edited as you advice, you have the decency to remove your down vote.

Comment: Blah, blah, blah ...
I'm pretty concise and concrete with my answer, while your's is confused, unclear and lacks any concrete code samples. Come back with something better please!

Comment: This is very discouraging. Given the speed of your answer, it is obvious, you did not have time to read and therefore judge how well I took half of your suggestion.  As I explained, I disagree with the other half. Nevertheless, your down vote is still in place, and by doing that, you made my effort pointless. That's not fair. You obviously realized my answer (while not well formatter) was better than yours so you made sure no one would read it by sinking it all the way to the bottom. You may have come up on top this time, but you did not win.

Answer (score 0):

You might use Duck Typing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Musician
{
    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    template <typename T>
    Musician(const T& other) : m_concept(new Model<T>(other))
    {}

    Musician(const Musician& other) : m_concept(other.m_concept->copy())
    {}

    Musician(Musician&& x) = default;

    Musician& operator = (Musician other) {
        m_concept = std::move(other.m_concept);
        return *this;
    }

    // Duck Typing Interface
    // =====================

    public:
    // Enable generic functionality
    friend void play(Musician& musician) { musician.m_concept->play(); }
    // Invoke external functionality
    template <typename T> static void invoke_play(T& musician) { play(musician); }

    // Concept
    // =======

    private:
    struct Concept
    {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual Concept* copy() = 0;
        virtual void play() = 0;
    };

    // Model
    // =====

    private:
    template <typename T>
    struct Model : Concept 
    {
        T object;

        Model(const T& other)
        : object(other) {}

        Concept* copy() override {
            return new Model(*this);
        }
        void play() override {
            invoke_play(object);
       }
    };

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Concept> m_concept;
};


// Test
// ====

class Saxophonist {};
class Pianist {};
class Bassist {};
class Drummer {};

void play(Saxophonist&) { std::cout << "Saxophone\n"; }
void play(Pianist&) { std::cout << "Piano\n"; }
void play(Bassist&) { std::cout << "Bass\n"; }
void play(Drummer&) { std::cout << "Drum\n"; }

using JazzQuartet = std::vector<Musician>;
void play(JazzQuartet& quartet) {
    for (auto& musician : quartet)
        play(musician);
}

int main() {
    JazzQuartet quartet;
    quartet.emplace_back(Saxophonist());
    quartet.emplace_back(Pianist());
    quartet.emplace_back(Bassist());
    quartet.emplace_back(Drummer());
    play(quartet);
}
```

This removes the need for any inheritance or (public) (virtual) interfaces. The basic model is more complicated, but realizations of the model are trivial.

Comment: Thank you, but this code is far beyond my understanding, I don´t even know where to start asking how it works...

Answer (score -1):

You might consider a type erasure pattern.  Sean Parent has been advocating using value types, and he often uses type erasure to do this with types that do not have a common base.  Overhead is the same as using an interface base class, but if you don't use the types in the context of erasure then there is no overhead.

Comment: You should give some more concrete relations and samples applying to the OP.